# Ember-cli creating more than 30000 files

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, bower, ember-cli, bower-install

I'm new to ember and after following a few guides, I've been playing around with ember apps. I'm using ember-cli to create an app, so I use

```
$ ember new 'app-name'
```

which creates the app as expected with the 'app' and 'dist' folder. But it also creates a lot of other files. I only discovered this while deleting the folder when the windows delete dialog box showed deleting more than 30000 files.

Is it that I'm doing something wrong that's causing unnecessary files to be created? Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong, a big portion of it is the dependencies and then the build process keeps a lot of temporary files around for reuse.

By the way, if you are developing in Windows, make sure you are running your command prompt as administrator, and that you've excluded the ember app from the virus scan, it really improves the build times.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it would be dependencies, presumably being created by bower. Is there a way to avoid it? Say like a global install so that it doesn't create this massive bulk of files for every single app?

Comment: There is no way to stop ember-cli from creating so many files. I am working on a really huge ember-cli project with more than 500 files. But actual number of files are quite large and size on disk for the project folder shows more than 2 GB on mac.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue with ember-cli itself, but how npm handles dependencies, since it has a hierarchical dependency system. You could try npm 3 (be warned, it's still beta - [changelog](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0)), which tries to flatten out the dependencies better.

Another thing is checking if bower packages are adding any unneeded dependencies, like tests or raw source files (if they have pre built files). You could submit a PR to those projects by adding the `ignore` property in the bower.json file. See the spec [here](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#ignore). Same with npm packages, which has a `.npmignore` file.

This is probably not what you wanted to hear, but in open source, we must all help each other. These are the bread crumbs of open source, and a great place to get started.